# default dpi resolutions with Xsane

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, scanning, dpi, xsane

when I scan a document with Xsane, I wonder why there are only these resolutions:
75,150,300,600,1200,2400,4800.

Why is there no resolution 100dpi? 75 is a little bit to small but 150 is already to big. Is there any reason why there are not any other resolutions than the upper ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the main Xsane menu, select View, then uncheck the Show Resolution List box (or you can toggle it with Ctrl-L). Then you will get the option to set any resolution that is available. )

It looks like this option is not available for all scanners.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for me. I neither have a resolution list box in the View menu nor can I toogle anything with CTRL-L. Maybe this doesn't work for CanoScan 8800F? But on the sane website there is written the following:
CanoScan 8800F  USB  0x04a9/0x1901  Complete  Flatbed scan. TPU for negatives and slides. All resolutions supported (up to 4800DPI).

Comment: Apparently it is a function of the scanner back end. I found an old thread (2000) that says if the back end defines a resolution list, then xsane takes the list exactly like it is, but if the back end defines a resolution range and the user chooses to display a list, then xsane generates a list, or else I guess you get a slider. My scanners use different back ends. One enables a slider for setting resolution and the other doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So does that mean that I can't change this behaviour?

Comment: I don't know. It could be a function of scanner firmware or a software limitation in the back end. See this link http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=39388 for a possible lead on who to contact for more information. Or you could scan at a higher resolution and reduce the resolution of the resulting file if you really need 100 dpi.